# How can install Odoo 13 on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, odoo

I am trying to install **odoo 13** on ubuntu 20.04 and it gives me this error when starting the installation, it has to do with the permissions from what I understand...

````
--2020-05-24 17:15:26--  https://nightly.odoo.com/odoo.key
Resolving nightly.odoo.com (nightly.odoo.com)... 178.33.123.40
Connecting to nightly.odoo.com (nightly.odoo.com)|178.33.123.40|:443... E: This command can only be used by root.
connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3112 (3,0K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

-                     0%[                    ]       0  --.-KB/s    in 0s      


Cannot write to ‘-’ (Success). ```
````

Comment: Ca you include the commands you used so far to get to this point? If you used apt-get or apt, try doing `sudo apt` or `sudo apt-get`.

Comment: Why the downvote? Users new to SO and/or computing may not know rules of engagement. If a newcomer isn't following recommendations over and over again, fine, but give them a chance and educate them of the expectations and let them respond to it.

Comment: use both commands and it doesn't allow me `sudo wget -O - https://nightly.odoo.com/odoo.key | apt-key add
--2020-05-24 17:53:27--  https://nightly.odoo.com/odoo.key
Resolving nightly.odoo.com (nightly.odoo.com)... E: This command can only be used by root.
178.33.123.40
Connecting to nightly.odoo.com (nightly.odoo.com)|178.33.123.40|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3112 (3,0K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’`

-                     0%[                    ]       0  --.-KB/s    in 0s      


Cannot write to ‘-’ (Success).

Comment: Try changing apt-key to `sudo apt-key` and try again.

Comment: tells me the following `sudo apt-key -O - https://nightly.odoo.com/odoo.key | apt-key add
E: This command can only be used by root.`

Comment: Try this `wget -qO - https://nightly.odoo.com/odoo.key | sudo apt-key add -`. Does that work for you? If that does, then you can do `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install <whatever you need to>`

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked for me, but the next step of the installation, when placing the following command tells me this `echo deb http://nightly.odoo.com/13.0/nightly/deb/ ./" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/odoo.list
bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/odoo.list: Permission denied`

Comment: Type `pwd`. It might be something like `/home/bob`. Note down the path. Then, do `sudo su -`. Then, type `cd /home/bob` or whatever that directory was. Then run the next steps of the installation (as root). If that solves the problem, let me know and I'll type in an answer for future reference.

Comment: yes it worked thanks

Comment: Great. I have typed in an answer for future reference. You are welcome to click on the check mark by the answer to put closure to your question, or you can wait for more answers to be published before selecting one answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here seemed to be that you are executing statements with a normal user but the script needs superuser privileges.

So, you should do this:

- Type `pwd` in your terminal. You will see the output to be the directory you are in currently. e.g. `/home/bob`. Write that down somewhere
- Type `sudo su -` and hit enter. If you are asked for a password, type your password
- That'll drop you into `root` user. Then, type `cd /home/bob` or whatever directory it was that you noted down previously
- Then, run remaining commands. You will be running them as root
- Once installation is complete, type `exit` and hit enter to exit out of `root` and get back to your normal user.

Be careful to run commands from a trustworthy source.